# WSGI Process/Thread Flags and Synchronization Confusion

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I've got a simple wsgi app running with Apache prefork MPM and i've been reading the [modwsgi docs on processes and threads](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading) (really good read). I'm still confused about a couple things and what would need synchronization.

**/1** If my Apache config is only a simple WSGIScriptAlias to my wsgi app like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /alias_name /path/to/wsgi/app.wsgi
```

and assuming prefork MPM Apache build, then the wsgi thread and process flags come in like this [wsgi.multiprocess = True, wsgi.multithread = False]. I understand this means a single process (no threads) is handling each request. And on these terms I wouldn't need to synchronize anything because I'm not doing any IPC between the processes and each process has its own address space. Is that correct thinking?

**/2** If my Apache config used WSGIDaemonPrcoesses however:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /alias_name /path/to/wsgi/app.wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi_proc_names processes=2 threads=2

WSGIProcessGroup  wsgi_proc_names
```

then the wsgi flags come in as [wsgi.multiprocess = true, wsgi.multithread = true] and there is a chance that the threads might step on each other's toes. Here is where I might need to synchronize access to certain data. If my application has no I/O then what else would need synchronization? For example, do class variables need to be locked on editing? Would functions that are being called by multiple threads need to be locked and released? This is what I am most confused about.

Thanks
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

Angelo,
As far as #1 goes your thinking seem solid.

Your second question (#2) is a little trickier. But as far as I know you'll need to lock on I/O (so in your case nothing). Each thread should have it's own call stack so i don't think you'll need to lock on functions. The only other thing that might need locking is global variables. But you didn't mention that you'd be using those.

Comment: thanks for the reply...finally a reply. Do you have any examples that I see maztaz?

Comment: I don't at hand, but maybe I can get something to you by the end of the day